# MySQL add up time duration of entries

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I have start times, duration and end times. How would I add up the duration of all entries to get a total time?

`id                     int(128) NO PRI NULL auto_increment
caller                 varbinary(16)
date_start             date
time_start             time
dir                    varbinary(64)
podcast                varbinary(64)
date_end               date
time_end               time
total_playing_time     time`

Thank you

Comment: `SELECT SUM(duration) FROM table;`?

Comment: The "`duration`" is in "time" i.e: `02:23:15` ... with your suggestion I do get a value `2253650` ... but I am not to sure if it is `225:36:50`

Comment: Can you add the table structure and expected output?

Comment: Darshan: Thank you for the help ...